# SQL aggregate function with if condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering if I can perform count function on different `status_id` with condition when `status_id` is `X` then something

This is my current query:

```
select count(*), status_id
from users
group by status_id
```

I would like to modify it to have extra condition: when `users.status_id` is in `(18,24,25)` then check if `users.active = true`. In all other cases no need to check the `users.active` column.

As of now I am doing following

```
select count(*), status_id
from users
where 1 = case when status_id in (18,24,25) 
           then (case when active = true then 1 else 0 end) 
          else 1 end
group by status_id
```

Is that the correct way to write query or there is a simpler way?

Thank you

Comment: No. If you tried to run it, you would see that the syntax is invalid. `FROM table AND` is not even close to being correct. Can you read [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) and [edit] your post with the table definitions, test data, and the output you want to obtain from that data?

Comment: If  e.g. status id 18 has only active false rows, do you want a result row for it with a 0 or do you want no result row for it?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), status_id
FROM users
WHERE status_id NOT IN (18, 24, 25) OR active = true
GROUP BY status_id
```

Comment: I still want to get the count of all `status_id` regardless user is active or not

Comment: @MikeRoss my query response is the same as the response of your query. As I understand, your query is working and you just want the simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include all status ids in the table in the results, even if the special case ones only have false active rows, then you want to do:

```
select sum(active or status_id not in (18,24,25)), status_id
from users
group by status_id
```